# How to stop the nav bar of a website from breaking items vertically? (see img below)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvGXQ.png)

I tried lots of things with div sizes, but nothing worked.
Here's my current code:

So, I've been trying to make it so that parts like the "about me" stays on the same height instead of one word going below the other, and same with all the icons. I want them to all be on the same height instead of one going over the other.

```html
<!---nav-bar-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo1.png"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
        <div class="nav-btn-container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="text-align: center;">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>About me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>Shop</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>My work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Script for navbar btn animation -->
  <script>
    function myFunction(x) {
      x.classList.toggle("change");
    }
  </script>
```

---

```css
/* navbar btn */
.nav-btn-container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Rotate first bar */
.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
}

/* Fade out the second bar */
.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* Rotate last bar */
.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
}
.navbar {
  padding: .8rem;
}
.navbar-nav li {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.1em !important;
}
```

Comment: Use `min-width`   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width

Comment: Thanks! didn't know anything about the existence of this property. If you could please add it as an answer so i can accept it, it worked. =) Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min-width`  you can find the documentation on [CSS min-width property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)

> The min-width CSS property sets the minimum width of an element. It
>   prevents the used value of the width property from becoming smaller
>   than the value specified for min-width.